# Coaxial and Triaxial connectors

Tags: current-measurement, cables, shielding

Can the coaxial cables be connected to a triaxal connector and other way around? I am asking this because I have a instrument that has BNC connectors, but I want to use triax for extra shielding. If not, how about the convertors between triax and coax, are they recommended?

Comment: Triax connectors are ridiculously expensive. You better be damn sure you need them, they're like $30 each, IIRC.

Comment: Did the extra shielding have the impact?  In the instruments which use triax cables, the outside shield is usually used for EMI shielding.  The inside shield is usually used for guarding to prevent DC leakages (similar to a guard ring on the PCB).

Answer (score 1):

This example of a [Triaxial to BNC-Female Adapter](http://www.testparts-store.com/trompeter-tei-adbj20-e1-pl75-triaxial-to-bnc-female-adapter-connector/) shows that:

- The two types cannot be directly connected without an adapter.
- There are adapters available.
- The adapters are not at all inexpensive.